# Invalid Component in Flow Builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I have Lightning Screen Flow with aura component inside.
The component has 'implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens"'.
But when updating flow I'm getting "Invalid Component" error and the component inaccessible in Screen Components list (but before it was) and the component wasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below syntax :-
<aura:component implements=”lightning:availableForFlowScreens” access=”global” >

2. Also check the naming convention of the aura component